# Can I import the old Facebook SDK beside new one 3.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to use some features for both the new Facebook SDK 3.0 and the deprecated one in the same class like this :

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "Facebook.h"
```

but I got some problems when importing these togethers in same class.

80% of my code are working on the new SDK 3.0 I just use the old one for the post and friend request but I cant use them at same time in the same class.

So is there any way to use them in the same `ViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it,,,

Instead of import all the library like this :

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

I Just import the only I need beside the old Facebook SDK like this :

```
#import "FBSession.h"
#import "FBProfilePictureView.h"
#import "FBRequestConnection.h"
#import "FBLoginView.h"
#import "Facebook.h"
```

And its working now :)

Answer (score 2):

No you can not do that directly, you can't have two classes with the same name in your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is symbolic links in FacebookSDK.framework folder, practically this folder looks like this

```
FacebookSDK -> ./Versions/A/FacebookSDK
Headers -> ./Versions/A/Headers
Resources -> ./Versions/A/Resources
```

So current version is /Versions/A/Headers , the old version is /Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders , you shout find way to mixed or to make "FacebookSDK_old.framework" for example and inside should be

```
Headers -> ./Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders
```